# ASP.NET - Determine which menu item is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is a little bit abstract:

I have a website written in ASP.NET MVC.  The end user can create a Menu object that will be displaced in the menu of the site.  This looks something like this:

```
public class Menu
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public Menu(string Caption, string Address)
    {
        this.Caption = Caption;
        this.Address = Address;
    }
}

public Menu Menu1 = new("Home", "/");
public Menu Menu2 = new("Events", "/events");
public Menu Menu3 = new("Specific Event", "/event/13");
```

When a request comes in, I need to be able to determine which menu item is "Active".  In addition, if a request is for a "subpage" of an item which is not explicitly named, the menu item should also be marked as active (e.g. if the request is for "/event/95/checkout", then Menu2 would be marked as active).

I was thinking about trying to figure compare the relative URL with the Address of the URLs to determine which matches the most characters, starting at the beginning of the string - but how would I go about doing that?  Is there perhaps a better way?

Comment: This seems like you're fighting MVC. Why are you not using things like `Url.Action()`?

Comment: Yea - I know what you mean - the issue is that I let the user create any link that they want on the Menu - not just something tied to a specific Action/Controller

Comment: I think a regular expression with greedy captures (i.e. try to match as many characters as possible) will work (ignoring all other possible alternatives, such as using route tables, as mentioned by @itsme86).

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar thing in our code. Our master page has a menu on the left, but one menu item can correlate to a range of sub pages.

The solution we went with was for each menu item to hold a list of regular expressions.

I'll give you a bunch of snippets of our code. This isn't a self-contained solution, but may give you ideas...

We would define our menu using a builder pattern (notice the method `UrlMatchPattern`)

```
var builder = new SiteMapBuilder();
builder.Add
       .Title("Home")
       .LaunchUrl("~/Home/Index")
       .IconUrl("~/Images/menuIcons/home.png")
       .UrlMatchPattern("~/Home/Index/?.*"); 
builder.Add
        .Title("Network")
        .IconUrl("~/Images/menuIcons/network.png")
        .Children(b => 
                    {
                        b.Add.Title("Companies")
                            .LaunchUrl("~/Company")
                            .UrlMatchPattern("~/Company");
                        b.Add.Title("Groups")
                            .LaunchUrl("~/PlayerGroup")
                            .UrlMatchPattern("~/PlayerGroup")
                            .LimitToRoles(
                                            CmsUserRoleId.Administrators, 
                                            CmsUserRoleId.Support
                                          );
                        b.Add.Title("Players")
                            .LaunchUrl("~/Player/index")
                            .UrlMatchPattern(
                                                @"~/\bPlayer\b", 
                                                "~/Player/Index", 
                                                @"~/Admin/PlayerDiagnostics\.aspx"
                                            );
```

This builder would dynamically rebuild the menu on each page request, generating a bunch of navigation panel nodes:

```
     internal NavPanelNode GenerateNode(IWebContext webContext, ...)
     {
            return new NavPanelNode
            {
                Title = _title,
                Url = _url,
                Children = _childNodeBuilder == null ? Enumerable.Empty<NavPanelNode>() : _childNodeBuilder.GenerateNodeHierachy(webContext, userContext),
                IsSelected = _urlMatchPattern.Any(pattern => webContext.MatchesPath(pattern)),
                IconUrl = _iconUrl
            };
   }
```

And my `MatchesPath` method:

```
    public static bool MatchesPath(this IWebContext webContext, System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex matchPattern)
    {
        string appRelativePath = webContext.CurrentRequestContext.GetAppRelativePath();
        return matchPattern.IsMatch(appRelativePath);
    }
```

As mentioned, our matching logic is via regular expressions.
Of course, if you're making this end-user configurable, you will have to let them configure the matching logic. I don't know how you will do this - it depends upon the user interface you're creating.